# How can I loop through a JSON array based on a variable?

Tags: javascript, json

I have already looped through my first JSON string and it gives me a variable value ("lstr") that is shown within a div. Based on this first value I'd like to loop through my second JSON string to populate a dropdown box. The variable value "lstr" matches the "name" object in jsonString2:

```
//resultItems.push("After");
         var lstr = "";

         for (var j = 2; j < resultItems.length; j++) {
             lstr = lstr + resultItems[j] + "";

         }
         dom.byId("info").innerHTML = lstr;

     });
```

jsonString2:

```
var jsonString2 = 

{
    "Toplevel": {
        "name": "Blue",
        "service": {
            "1": "a url",
            "2": "a url",
            "3": "a url",
        },
        "name": "Green",
        "service": {
            "1": "a url",
            "2": "a url",
            "3": "a url",

        },
        "name": "Yellow",
        "service": {
            "1": "a url",
            "2": "a url",
            "3": "a url",

        }
    }
}
```

Depending on the the "lstr" value being blue, green or yellow it would then populate a dropdown box with the 1,2,3 objects and their related url values. I hope this makes sense? Any help would be good?!

Comment: You're using `post` or `get` in this variable to populate the dropdown?

Comment: Your JSON2 object makes this near impossible. Since objects are unsorted in JS - there's no way to see what "service" property relates to each name... is this supposed to be an array?

Comment: Your `jsonString2` is broken. The keys `name` and `service` are present 3 times, so `Blue` and `Green` will never exist, because they are overwritten by `Yellow`.

Answer (score 0):

Like the comments have said, you need to re factor your second JSON object (jsonString2) to look like this:

```
    var jsonString2 = 

{
    "Toplevel": {
      "Blue": {
         "service": {
            "1": "a url",
            "2": "a url",
            "3": "a url",
          }
        },
        "Green" : {
           "service": {
            "1": "a url",
            "2": "a url",
            "3": "a url",
           }
         },
        "Yellow" : {
          "service": {
            "1": "a url",
            "2": "a url",
            "3": "a url",
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use

```
for (var key in jsonStrng2[lstr].service){
 //add code to update dropdown here for each service
}
```